# Calling react function through props, invoke once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table that have a function that runs on row click:

```
onRowClick: function(row){
        selectedRow = (row.id);
        props.handelExpand;
}
```

The problem is the handelExpand function that comes form another class is not being invoked:

```
handelExpand={this.doExpand}
```

with the code above the function is not being invoked. So I tried this:

```
handelExpand={()=>this.doExpand}
```

Same result. Then I tried this:

```
handelExpand={this.doExpand()}
```

It worked, but function is invoked repeatedly.

How to I make it run only once (only when onRowClick is invoked)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
handelExpand={this.doExpand}

onRowClick: function(row){
    selectedRow = (row.id);
    props.handelExpand();
```

}

You are not calling the function.

Comment: That worked, Thanks. I have to wait 8 more minutes to give best answer.

Comment: Can I also pass a parameter to handelExpand like this props.handelExpand(row)? if possible how do I pass the same parameter to this.DoExpand?

Comment: You can simply pass args like a normal function call and then use it inside the function.